# How to write an SQL query for this scenario?

Tags: sql

I have a table containing attributes `Id, Emp_name, dept_name, salary`. Now i want to write an SQL query that will give me the `dept_name` value for which the overall salary of all employees belonging to that department is the highest, i.e dept for which sum of salaries of all its employees is the highest...? If there is any similar question with answer on stackoverflow, please suggest.. I dint find one. Thanks :)

I tried `group by` with `sum()` function, but i could not get how to find the maximum and compare it with sum.

Comment: which database are you using?

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried?

Comment: I am using mysql database. And what i tried is, SELECT dept FROM table_name GROUP BY dept HAVING sum(salary) = ? This is how i was stuck.. I dont even know whether its the right approach..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you do

```
    SELECT TOP 1 dept_name FROM table GROUP BY dept_name ORDER BY SUM(salary) DESC
```

Comment: Whats this TOP...? Is that a keyword used in SQL..?

Comment: Yes, SELECT TOP n returns the first n rows from the result.  You can also do SELECT TOP n PERCENT

Comment: Yes, i got it.. Thanks Bort :)

Comment: @Kishan - Is an SQL clause that retrieves the top N records following the `ORDER` clause. But this is **not supported on all database systems, so its not standard**. You can check this link to get more information: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp

Comment: I guess `TOP` is not supported in MySQL. Instead `LIMIT` is used. Anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a textbook example for GROUP BY:

```
select dept_name, total_salary from (
  Select dept_name, sum(salary) as total_salary
  from my_table
  group by dept_name
) order by total_salary desc
```

Comment: This returns one row for each department.

Comment: Thanks, will this select only the department corresponding to maximum salary...? I think it displays them in descending order..

Answer (score 0):

try this:

select top 1 dept_name from myTable group by dept_name order by sum(salary) desc

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT dept_name FROM table
GROUP BY dept_name
ORDER BY SUM(salary) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

And you would also better have you departments in another table linked to the first table via foregn keys. Just a note.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly know your requirements, but perhaps there is another point to be considered: Two (or more) departments could have the same sum of salary.

I have not tested the query, but this should give you all departments which have the maximum some of salary:

select dept_name FROM table_name GROUP BY dept_name HAVING SUM(salary)=(select MAX(sum_salary) FROM (select SUM(salary) AS sum_salary FROM table_name GROUP BY dept_name))